# RightClick context not showing on outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook Office add-in, and need to allow the user to right click to choose a previously selected option from context menu.

Everything was working until I updated Windows 10 and Outlook. Now it is not working.

**Windows Version**

[image]

**Outlook version**
[image]

**OfficeJs Version**

host: Outlook, 
version: 16.0.12026.20190, 
platform: PC,

I wanted to enable right click menu as follows:

[image]

[Edit] My desktop outlook add-in is using edge web-view

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "context menu?" Is this inside your add-in view or somewhere in outlook?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I meant Right Click Menu Option

Comment: This is a known issue with the Edge WebView and we are working with the Edge team to address it.

Comment: You may be able to use Javascript to create custom menus for your add-in to workaround